# Facebook opengraph -- custom object and action -- There needs to exist at least one story for username:action

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been using the facebook APIs to create custom opengraph objects with the Web api. I have been successful using the built-in actions and objects, like "news.reads" and "article", but I want to create my own action and object instead.

I have created a custom object and custom action for that object through the developers.facebook.com apps interface (I created an app and created a custom object and custom action). We'll call the action "eats" and the object "bananas" for now.

I create both of these in the interface, go back to my code, and replace with these values. However, when the share dialog pops up, it gives the error "There needs to exist at least one story for username:eats."

I went to the Stories tab on the Open Graph page of the app interface and created a custom story with my custom type and custom object. I went back to my site, same error.

Are these the "stories" this error is speaking of? It seemed to make sense to me, but nothing has changed since I have created one of the stories they spoke of. Does anyone have an idea of how to solve the "There needs to exist at least one story for username:action" error?

Because my code worked before with built-in actions and objects, I'm pretty sure it's something to do with this story they keep speaking of. There's been talk of needing to go through the review process, but I am assuming that only has to do with wanting to push something live, right? I'm content to test for now.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I was providing the object ID as a parameter for the action's variable name (which corresponds to the object), but I also needed to provide the object ID as another parameter.

So, I had to supply the same object ID twice as two separate parameters, one for the action object name and one for the story object name (the name of the story parameter was the name of the object type).

My parameters thus looked like:

```
[actionVariableNameForObject] = [objectID]
[objectTypeName] = [objectID]
```

This was on iOS though so the above is pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

not guaranteed to help, but when I got this error, I had to open "bananas", save it (without changing anything), do the same for "eat",  rinse and repeat with the story itself. After that it worked for me.